# Click innertext on website in a new window with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm beginning to use VBA to interact with websites and I stumbled in a problem I couldn't find a solution here. 
I'm trying to click on a text that appears on a "new window" (which is not a new window, it's just a square that shows on top of the page and dissapears when I click on the desired line). Here is the code from that "square":

```
<div id="retornoBuscaDados"><table style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 
0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 500px;"><tbody><tr class="par"> 
<td style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer;">nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn 
nnnnnnn </td></tr><tr class="impar"><td nowrap="" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr><tr class="par"><td nowrap="" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr 
class="impar"><td nowrap="" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="par"><td 
nowrap="" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="impar"><td nowrap="" 
colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class="par"><td nowrap="" colspan="1">&nbsp; 
</td></tr><tr class="impar"><td nowrap="" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr 
class="par"><td nowrap="" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

The code from the exact line that I want to click is:

```
<td style="width: 100px; cursor: pointer;">
```

But what that line is showing is the text "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" (I replaced the actual text to show to you). All the other lines are blank.
I don't know what I can do since until now I was only using getelementbyid("xx").click for the other click steps on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Internet Explorer (though the CSS selector combination can be applied to HTML document populated from XMLHTTP request)

```
ie.document.querySelector("#retornoBuscaDados td").Click
```

Also assuming not in a parent frame/iframe/new window and that you have left time for page to load before attempting to click i.e.

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
ie.document.querySelector("#retornoBuscaDados td").Click
```

querySelector returns the first match for the specified pattern. The pattern `#retornoBuscaDados td` is looking for a parent element with id `retornoBuscaDados` having a child `td` element. It will retrieve the first child in this instance. You could also use a pseudo selector of `#retornoBuscaDados td:first-child`

Comment: So easy! Thank you @QHarr for your explanation, it was very didactic!